# DateTime.ParseExact is failing (string not valid datetime format)

Tags: c#

I am trying to use DateTime.ParseExact on a timestamp that uses the format `M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff` and the compiler is telling me that this is not going to happen.

An example of my timestamp is:

`3/26/2013 14:37:05:553`

...and an example of my code is, where _CultureInfo is en-us.

`DateTime someDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("3/26/2013 14:37:05:553","M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", _CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat);`

See below image of what's going on... am I missing something?

[image]

**New Edit**

I've tried a couple more things with still no luck:

- Changing `:fff` to `.fff`
- Changing `_CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat` to `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and changing the `d` to `dd` as suggested below

Below is something you can throw into a Console and run to see exactly how this is behaving on my end.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CsvImporter importer = new CsvImporter();

            DateTime readtime = importer.Parse(@"""3/26/2013 14:37:07:238,00:00:01.6850000,23.138,23.488,23.175""");

            Console.WriteLine(readtime.ToString());
        }
    }

    class CsvImporter
    {
        public Char[] _SeparatorChars = new Char[] { ',' };

        public DateTime Parse(string text)
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo _CultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

            string txt = text.Replace('"', ' ');
            string[] columns = txt.Split(_SeparatorChars);

            return DateTime.ParseExact(columns[0], "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", _CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat);
            //return DateTime.ParseExact(columns[0], "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It parses just fine on my machine (created `var _CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-us");`, then copy pasted your line below it)

Comment: @C.Evenhuis How? `CultureInfo` doen't have `DateTimeFormat`

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine.

Can you check whether your CultureInfo really is en-us? What platform are your targetting? (WinForms, XAML, Windows Phone, ...)

Comment: @I4V mine does (.NET 4 Client Profile)

Comment: Yes, verify that your CultureInfo is en-US.  You can do this through `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

Comment: This is all called via a windows service.  I did, however, just realize that this class library targets .NET 2.0... And to answer the "is this really en-us," yes -- it is.

Comment: Bringing it up to .NET 4.0 didn't do anything.

Comment: Usually fractions of a second are separated from the seconds with a period, not a colon.  Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: I will try that.  I know we use a colon in another situation in the same service.  I also am not seeing any fraction defined in the DateTimeFormatInfo, but I don't believe that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `string txt = text.Replace('"', ' ');`

This is turning `column[0]` into `[space]3/26/2013 14:37:05:553` instead of `3/26/2013 14:37:05:553` like I'd expect.

Changing this line to `string txt = text.Replace(@"""", "");` solves the problem.

Comment: Or just use trim instead of replace just in case `"` is found in the middle as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (Changed `d` to `dd` and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` )

```
DateTime someDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("3/26/2013 14:37:05:553", "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `ParseExact`, make sure you're using an unambiguous format string. In .NET, the `/` character in a format string is the [system date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), not an actual slash. Same for the `:` character in times.

To parse a string with your structure, escape out the slashes and colons with backslashes, like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"M\/d\/yyyy HH\:mm\:ss\:fff", null)
// or
DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M\\/d\\/yyyy HH\\:mm\\:ss\\:fff", null)
```

This will tell the parser that you specifically want the forward-slash and colon, regardless of your system preferences or current culture.